# Perl on Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite with strange @INC path

Tags: perl, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to OS 10.10 I had to install all former used perl modules again. No problem. I thought.

Perl on OS 10.10 is "This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level" (from perl --version).
The @INC looks to be (try perl -e 'print join("\n", @INC);' or perl -V):

/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
  /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl

When I try to use an unknown module, perl throws:
"Can't locate Mymodule.pm in @INC ... and then: @INC contains: ... /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 and all other known (and added 5.18 perl.pm folders).
Every perl dev knows that message.
But read literally: @INC links obviously to 5.18 folders ! And at a first glance I supposed to use Perl 5.18.

I installed my first bunch of new modules from Macports. 5.18 portfiles. And added the new module pathes to the list /Library/Perl/5.18/AppendToPath. Worked well.
But when I installed a module - not available as 5.18 in Macports - with cpan, I got trouble. The module was compiled with 5.16 (of course, see above) and was not accepted as other path in the AppendToPath file. Dynaloader mismatch.

I do not know, where the @INC list is altered at runtime. In earlier Mac OS 10 versions, the new @INC included same version module versions. I.e. an active perl 5.14 included also 5.14 modules, 5.12 included 5.12 pathes a.s.o.
Why does perl 5.16 on Yosemite include 5.18 module pathes ?

---

To add some confusion after my post: 
When I try a print $^V in program code, I get 5.18. 
That means, you don't get what you meant to get. May be my shebang #!/usr/bin/perl starts 5.18 and not 5.16.

Comment: Check your setting of PERL5LIB or PERLLIB environment variables (`echo $PERL5LIB` etc).

Comment: I’d use Perlbrew if possible. Messing with system or MacPorts Perl is always bound to be trouble.

Comment: I have checked this of course. Both are empty. Notice, I edited my post. A question of perl --version means somewhat other as what is started with the shebang.

Comment: I think to know the reason what's going on here. The shebang really calls a perl bin in /usr/bin. The question "which perl" shows /opt/local/bin/perl (a symlink to perl 5.16). /usr/bin/perl is obviously a perl 5.18. I thing I have to configure my cpan to use 5.18. Thank you friend for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

Experienced Perl developers will tell you to ignore the system perl.  If you upgrade it, for a bugfix you need, you run the risk of breaking your OS.  If you upgrade your OS, a modified system perl may break your code.

Macports and homebrew are both great, but not ideal for Perl.  I'd clear the /opt/local/version from my PATH, or even my system.

Do yourself a big favor.  Install `Xcode` with the `Command Line Tools`.  Install `perlbrew`.  Roll up your own perl.  Heck, roll up 6 of your own perls and jump back and forth between them.  Keep a threaded version around for when you need it.  Keep a non-threaded around for speed.  Best of all, whenever you change which version you are using, perlbrew updates your environment correctly for you.  No fuss, No muss.

Answer (score 3):

**Solved**

OS Yosemite as an update from Maverick provides perl 5.16 *and* 5.18.
When testing `which perl`you will get `/opt/local/bin/perl`, which is a symlink to `/opt/local/bin/perl5.16`.

When you use `#!/usr/bin/perl`as standard shebang in perl programs (portable i.e. to Linux), you will run this program with another perl version, because `#!/usr/bin/perl` really exists as a binary with version 5.18.

When you use cpan / cpanm (cpanminus) for easy and quick installation of new modules, you'll get the modules compiled as 5.16 versions. Because this is assumed as standard path / version (see above).

You will find `cpanm` at `/opt/local/libexec/perl5.16/sitebin/` 
You also will find `/opt/local/libexec/perl5.18/` but no sitebin and no cpanm.

And now: 
Create a folder `sitebin` in `/opt/local/libexec/perl5.18/` and copy the file `/opt/local/libexec/perl5.16/sitebin/cpanm` to `/opt/local/libexec/perl5.18/sitebin/` (use sudo ... to get permissions).

cpanm is a normal perl program file, independent from versions - but watch the shebang of this file! Open the file and edit the first two lines from

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl5.16 
eval 'exec /opt/local/bin/perl5.16  -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
```

to

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl5.18 
eval 'exec /opt/local/bin/perl5.18  -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
```

that means: simply change 5.16 to 5.18. That's all.

Now you are able to install new modules with this new cpanm. 
The new cpanm will deploy the modules in `/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/`. To let the new path know to perl 5.18 on Mac edit the file `/Library/perl/5.18/AppendToPath` and append a new line with `/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level` (without slash at the end).

That's it.

Comment: The /opt/local/bin/perl is not part of Yosemite.  It's probably left over from an old Macports install.  I'd loose it entirely, or at least drop it from my path...

Comment: I think, that's a reclict from Maverick or Mountain Lion

Comment: If it was, I'd have it on my Mac too.  My bet is still on Macports.